# getting multiple customer details In codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i have written this code to receive data from the Android device. it was inserted just one customer data I need to receive multiple customer details if app goes offline. but it was inserting one data into DB in offline mode also.how can i change this for multiple customer data insertions.

```
function index_post($customerID = false) {
    if ($customerID) {
        //update the record
        $updateData = array();
        $allowedparams = array('streetid' => 'streetid', 'name' => 'name', 'mobile' => 'mobile', 'adhaar' => 'adhaar', 'profession' => 'profession', 'address' => 'address', 'pincode' => 'pincode', 'nearby' => 'nearby', 'paddress' => 'paddress', 'isOwned' => 'isOwned');
        foreach ($allowedparams as $k => $v) {
            if (!$this->IsNullOrEmptyString($this->post($k, true))) {
                $updateData[$v] = $this->post($k, true);
            }
        }
        if ($this->model_customer->update($customerID, $updateData)) {
            $data = array('status' => true, 'messsage' => 'cusotmer updated succesfully');
            $http_code = REST_Controller::HTTP_OK;
        } else {
            $data = array('status' => false, 'messsage' => 'cusotmer failed to update.');
            $http_code = REST_Controller::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        }
    } else {
        //insert the record
        $allowedparams = array('streetid' => 'streetid', 'name' => 'name', 'mobile' => 'mobile', 'adhaar' => 'adhaar', 'profession' => 'profession', 'address' => 'address', 'pincode' => 'pincode', 'cycle' => 'cycle', 'nearby' => 'nearby', 'paddress' => 'paddress', 'isOwned' => 'isOwned');
        $requiredParam = array('streetid', 'name', 'mobile', 'cycle');
        $insertdata = array();
        foreach ($allowedparams as $k => $v) {
            if (in_array($k, $requiredParam)) {
                //check if its not null
                if ($this->post($k) == null || trim($this->post($k)) == '') {
                    $data = array('status' => false, 'message' => $k . ' parameter missing or empty');
                    $http_code = REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
                    break;
                }
            }
            $insertData[$v] = $this->post($k, true);
        }
        if ($customerID = $this->model_customer->create($insertData)) {

            $data['customerID'] = $this->_frameCustomer2($this->model_customer->get($customerID));  //you need to put
            $http_code = REST_Controller::HTTP_OK;
        } else {
            $data = array('status' => false, 'message' => 'unable to create customer');
            $http_code = REST_Controller::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        }
    }
    $this->response($data, $http_code);
}
private function _frameCustomer2($c) {                       //get value from index_get
    $data = array();
    $data['id'] = $c->id;
    $data['name'] = $c->name;
    $data['street'] = array('id' => $c->streetid);
    $data['creationDate'] = $c->creationdate;
    $data['mobile'] = $c->mobile;
    $data['adhaar'] = $c->adhaar;
    $data['profession'] = $c->profession;
    $data['isOwned'] = ($c->isOwned == 1) ? true : false;
    $data['address'] = $c->address;
    $data['pincode'] = $c->pincode;
    $data['status'] = $c->status;
    $data['cycle'] = $c->cycle;
    $data['balance'] = $c->balance;
    $data['creditAvailable'] = $c->creditbalance;
    $data['nearby'] = $c->nearby;
    $data['accountNumber'] = $c->accountnumber;
    $data['permanentAddress'] = $c->paddress;
    $data['lastVisit'] = $this->model_customer->lastVisit($c->id);
    return $data;
}
```

and my part of model function is

```
function create($insertdata = array()) {                             //new customer insert
    if ($this->db->insert('customer', $insertdata)) {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function update($customerID = 0, $updateData = array()) {
    $this->db->where('id', $customerID);
    if ($this->db->update('customer', $updateData) && $this->db->affected_rows() == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of customer Id, you can ask the mobile developers to send data in the form of array. In both online and offline. In case of online there will be just one element in the request array.

```
function index_post() {
    $request_data = $this->request->body;
    foreach($request_data as $key => $value)
    {
        //Check if customer id is present 
       if(Customer present)
       {
           Update the record
       } else {
           Insert the record
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you face any issue further.

Comment: no @Gauri my previous code was worked successfully.that was not our fault that fault occurs on android devices. they solved that. anyway thankyou again